# Как сделать наследование по прототипу javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

Пробую делать элементарное наследование

```
function hot () {
  this.time = 44;
  this.has = true
}

function hot2 () {
  this.desc = 'some';
}


hot2.prototype = hot();

var f = new hot2();
console.log(f.has);
```

пишет undefined почему я не могу получить доступ к переменным функции hot через екземпляр hot2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот тут вы устанавливаете прототип в null, так как простой вызов функции `hot` не вернёт ничего:

```
hot2.prototype = hot();
```

Для того, чтобы прототипом стал объект с нужными вам полями, создайте экземпляр:

```
hot2.prototype = new hot();
```

или верните `this` (данный вариант лучше не использовать):

```
function hot () {
   this.time = 44;
   this.has = true;
   return this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще почитайте про [наследование](https://learn.javascript.ru/class-inheritance). Как-то странно у вас тут. Ваша функция `hot` ничего не возвращает, а вы её после вызова еще и в prototype запихиваете. Вот так будет получше:

```
function hot () {
  return {
    time: 44,
    has: true
  }
}

function hot2 () {
  this.desc = 'some';
}


hot2.prototype = hot();

var f = new hot2();
console.log(f.has);
```